# Java - Esperar um método para executar proxima instrução

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo um aplicativo CRUD em Android para o projeto da faculdade. Estou usando um `ImageButton` para a pessoa selecionar a imagem a ser salvar. A parte de selecionar a imagem e ela ficar armazenada está funcionando bem; mas a foto na view `ImageButton` não muda.

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galeria, "Selecione a imagem"), 32);
btimg.setImageBitmap(imagemselecionada2);
```

Pelo que percebi este `btimg.setImageBitmap` esta rodando antes da instrucao anterior selecionar uma imagem. Teria como eu fazer ele rodar soh depois que a `startActivity` acima terminar de rodar?

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, cara eu uma vez tive que sobrescrever o método abaixo, pois após o usuario selecionar a imagem, o Android retorna a intent e o foco para sua activity e executa o método abaixo:

```
@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int ResultCode, Intent intent){
  if(requestCode == 32){
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

      //seu codigo aqui
      btimg.setImageBitmap(imagemselecionada2);
    }
}}
```

Talvez te ajude!

Comment: Cara, obrigado pela resposta. Mas infelizmente não funcionou. Eu nao consigo setar para ele pegar esse "btimg'' pois sempre que coloco ele no metodo OnCreate() ele fica aparecendo uns erros . E fora do OnCreate ele nao consegue pegar o objeto btimg. :( O que fazer?

Comment: A pergunta é de cinco anos atrás (no momento que escrevo isso) mas só para constar, o raciocínio está correto. Esse método `onActivityResult()` é chamado no retorno de uma comunicação com outra activity, então tem que mover o código que seta o bitmap para dentro desse método (ajustando o escopo das variáveis conforme necessário) e pegar o conteúdo do bitmap a partir do intent retornado (ou então somente algum tipo de identificador do bitmap, número ou string, usando o mesmo para se extrair o bitmap de alguma fonte).